# PHP-MYSQL-Innodb Slow on Insert

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

Currently I have built a PHP script to import a large data set into a Innodb Table.
This script reads a record from a file, builds multiple queries (the data is highly relational) and inserts them into the database.  I created this script on a fresh debian VM built with one core and 2GB of memory.

To be clear, by fresh I mean that it was a clean image with only the packages mysql-server mysql-client and php5 installed.

When running the script in the VM 2 of the data files (60MB+ each) completed in under 8 seconds inserting over 5,000 records.

Then I moved this script over to the server that currently holds the data and will hold the database.  This server has 28GB RAM, and 2 XEON(6core) processors.  It is also a fresh install with default mysql-client, mysql-server, and php5-cli installed.  To be clear, the database is empty when the script begins and the server has no other processes running other than SSH and standard system processes.

When running the script on this server it moves extremely slow (30 seconds and only 180 records are inserted).

I have tried skip-name-resolve in the my.cnf file, but it seems to do nothing.  While the script is running if I view the processlist in mysql I see insert queries constantly in the "freeing items" state. Any ideas as to what could cause the slowdown?

Here is the my.cnf on the server giving issues::

```
[client]

port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
language        = /usr/share/mysql/english
skip-external-locking
skip-name-resolve
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer              = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed 
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error logging goes to syslog due to /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf. 
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id              = 1
#log_bin                        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db           = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db       = include_database_name
```

Comment: You probably need to give more information if you want accurate answers. The problem may be with your mysql configuration files...

Comment: It could be any number of things.  What else is running on the server? What is the network traffic like? Ram usage? What cron jobs are running? How many rows are in the database already? What is your database schema? Etc etc etc... Please try to localize your question and ask something specific.  We can't log into your server and solve your problem for you.

Comment: Reveal the code that prepares and inserts the SQL to the db

Comment: It could not be the schema because the same schema is running in the VM at a reasonable pace.  The server is the exact same setup as the VM meaning, it is empty with no web servers, no mysql connections other than the script, no cron jobs, no background processes etc.  The question is what could cause mysql to run so much slower on a system with much more horsepower?

Comment: Sure it *never*  is the schema, it is the phase of the moon in relation of the earth in place to the sun and mars.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the problem. On the development server the database was originally MyISAM but was converted to Innodb during development. This caused transactions and auto commit to be disabled.

When moving to the new server, the database was created as Innodb from the start, making transactions and auto commit active.

This caused MySQL to auto commit after each query causing dramatic slowdown.

The fix then was to add the query,

```
Start transaction
```

Before loading each file and then committing immediately afterwards.

Performance now surpasses the VM.

Comment: Then you may mark your own answer as accepted.